# Implementing hovercard mouseout event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I'm implementing hovercards for my website. The hovercard shows up on hovering over any username. I use the mouseenter event to load the hovercard and mouseout to hide it.

```
//HTML
<span class="hover_div">
    <a class="show_hovercard" user_name="gaurav">Gaurav</a>
</span>

// JavaScript
$('.show_hovercard').on({
   'mouseenter': function(e) {
       var $current_node = $(this);
       var $parent = $current_node.parent();
       var markup = "<p class='hovercard'>Gaurav's hovercard</p>";
       $parent.append(markup);
    }
});

$('.hover_div').on({
   'mouseout': function(e) {
        var $hovercard = $(this).find('.hovercard');
        $hovercard.remove();
    }
});
```

the class .hovercard is absolute positioned.

I want the hovercard to not hide when moving from the username to the card. But when I move from the username to the hovercard, the hovercard is getting hidden. What should be done?

Here is working jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/L6D47/1

Comment: Please provide a working example including CSS on jsFiddle or something alike, makes helping you so much easier

Comment: I added a link to a working jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error in your javascript syntax.

Your Code:

```
$('.hover_div').on({
   '.mouseout': function(e) {
        var $hovercard = $(this).find('.hovercard');
        $hovercard.remove();
    }
});
```

Should be:

```
$('.hover_div').on({
   'mouseout': function(e) {
        var $hovercard = $(this).find('.hovercard');
        $hovercard.remove();
    }
});
```

UPDATE:
I've managed to solve your problem. Change the p element to a div element as the p element has a margin and is not consistent. Then change mouseout to mouseleave. Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NLXkV/6/

Comment: Thanks for the response Ovidiu. That was a typo. Corrected. Can you please help

Comment: But I want the margin to remain. Also, Is it possible to delay the mouseleave event from firing. It's be great if the hovercard would hide only when the mouse leaves the hover_div for more than, say, a second.

Comment: You can use a setTimeout on the remove action like so: setTimeout(function(){$hovercard.remove();},1000); instead of just: $hovercard.remove();

Also for the margin, you can use nested divs to achieve the same visual effect. as long as the first div is right next to the target link, you should be fine.

Comment: But the problem with this is that hovercard will be removed after a second anyway. I want to not remove the hovercard if the mouse is back again in the hover_div before a second passes.

Comment: I think you will have to ask another question or edit the current one with new progress as this is getting more complicated.